# math need a number between -180 and 180

Tags: java

I have a math problem.

In minecraft the yaw can be between -180 and 180 now I need to add 90 to the player his yaw. but if the yaw is 150 + 90 = 240 that is more than 180, how can I add 90 but if it passes 180 count further on -180.

Examples:

```
-150 + 90 = -60, No problem
0 + 90 = 90, No problem
150 + 90 = 240, Problem it needs to be -120
```

Comment: *"Problem it needs to be 60"*, wrong it should be *-120*. At least according to your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
private static final int MIN = -180;
private static final int MAX = 180;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(keepInRange(-150 + 90));
    System.out.println(keepInRange(0 + 90));
    System.out.println(keepInRange(150 + 90));
    System.out.println(keepInRange(-150 - 90));
}

private static int keepInRange(final int value) {
    if (value < MIN) {
        /*
         * subtract the negative number "MIN" from "value" and
         * add the negative result to "MAX" (which is like subtracting the absolute value
         * of "value" from "MAX)
         */
        return MAX + (value - MIN);
    }
    if (value > MAX) {
        /*
         * subtract the number "MAX" from "value" and to get exceeding number
         * add it to "MIN"
         */
        return MIN + (value - MAX);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The output is:

> -60
>   90
>   -120
>   120

According to your explanation, the last to values should be *-120* and *120* and not *-60* and *60* like you said in your example. The exceeding amount should be added to the "other" bound, and not from *0*. `150 + 90` is *240*, so it exceeds the MAX bound by 60. This then should be added to the MIN bound. The result is *-120*.

If this is not correct, then please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of modular arithmetic. You can use the remainder operator `%`.

```
    int current = 150;
    int input = 90;
    int newCurrent = ((180 + current + input) % 360) - 180;

    System.out.println("NEW: " + newCurrent);
```

The output is:

```
 NEW: -120
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator for positive numbers, this looks like a division but gives you the rest instead of the quotient:

```
10/6 = 1,66666...
10%6 = 4

For you: ( 150 + 90 ) % 180 = 60
```